# nginx fails to load a file - ssl certificate - even if its clearly there

Tags: nginx, ssl

I want to use ssl with nginx. I create the necessary certificates:

```
[root@arch ssl]# pwd
/etc/nginx/ssl
[root@arch ssl]# ls -l
total 12
-rwx------ 1 root root 1346 Aug  3 14:36 server.crt
-rwx------ 1 root root 1115 Aug  3 14:36 server.csr
-rwx------ 1 root root 1743 Aug  3 14:35 server.key
```

But nginx fails to load these files. It says it can't find them:

```
systemctl -l status nginx

nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2014-08-03 14:50:04 EDT; 21min ago
Process: 21391 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 16458 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 03 14:50:04 arch nginx[21391]: 2014/08/03 14:50:04 [emerg] 21391#0:     BIO_new_file("/etc/gninx/ssl/server.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system     library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/gninx/ssl/server.crt','r')     error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
Aug 03 14:50:04 arch systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited     status=1
Aug 03 14:50:04 arch systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Aug 03 14:50:04 arch systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

This is the config that I have:

```
server {


   server_name localhost;
   listen 443;
   ssi on;        


   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/gninx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

   client_max_body_size 4G;



   location =  / {
       ...
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell me please what I;m missing?

Thanks in advance for your kind help and time.

Jenia.

Comment: You misspelled `nginx` as `gninx`.

Answer (score 7):

I'll bet `nginx` is not running as root. The permissions you have on the key/cert pair is readable only by root.

I usually create a `www` group and make the key `root:www 440` and the cert `root:www 444` (the cert is sent out publically for every connection; so there's no reason to keep it secret; just make sure it's uneditable). Then I make sure that `apache` (or `nginx` as you prefer) runs as `www:www`.

--oh yah...
Make sure that you don't have a pass phrase on the key; or if you do (it ~is~ better security), make sure that `nginx` has a provision to allow you to submit the pass phrase as you initiate it. (sorry, I've never tried to use `nginx`). And then be prepared for it to hang and wait every time it restarts until you can reach the console.

Comment: thanks for the pass phrase hint it was the source to my issue :)

Answer (score 7):

The problem was the route, as you set /etc/**gninx**/ssl/server.crt; which should be /etc/**nginx**/ssl/server.crt;